# Can I use a %variable% in module section of codeception environment file?

Tags: codeception

I tried to have the server address injected to the test with environment variable ABSOLUTE_URL so [PhpBrowser](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser) would test against it. The config I wanted to do is something like this:

```yaml
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser:
            url: "%ABSOLUTE_URL%"
```

But I simply could not get it to work. Is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add params section to codeception.yaml file:

```yaml
params:
    - env
```

Documented at https://codeception.com/docs/06-ModulesAndHelpers#Dynamic-Configuration-With-Parameters